Algorithm that generates an event of probability $\frac{1}{n}$ for given an arbitrary random variable.
My teacher gave me this problem. We have a controller that each turn takes two numbers: a value-to-write $v_n$ and value from random generator $g_n$. It's required to write an algorithm such that after stopping after n-th turn yields one of the values-to-write met on turns 1,...,n (each value should appear equally likely). Also, it must store O(1) numbers in memory. Random generator represents some random variable with unknown probability density.
If we know the variable $\xi$ represented random generator, then solution is pretty easy. The algorithm will be:
Store in memory $n$ - number of turns taken, $x$ - current value.
On n-th turn:
if $P(\xi < g_n) < \frac{1}{n}$, write $g_n$ to $x$. Otherwise, do nothing.
However, without knowing $\xi$, problem seems to me unsolvable, as for example, if stopped after 2nd iteration, algorithm should yield each $v_1$ and $v_2$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. But how can we generate an event with probability $\frac{1
}{2}$ without knowing $\xi$?
Any help would be appreciated. Possibly, I understood the problem incorrectly, so you could suggest more logical interpretation.

Well, the order of the random variables is a $\frac 12$ matter.  That is, with $n=2$, the max is equally likely to be $g_1$ or $g_2$ (I'm assuming that none of the $g_i$ can coincide).  Similarly, for general $n$, the maximum $g_i$ is equally likely to appear in any position, and you only need to retain the current max and it's location.
